# Calculating probability of an event that has almost but not happened yet

Tags: probability, rare-events

I have a series of data that follows no distribution and can't be transformed.

The data indicates concentration levels that are about 99% of the time OK (very close to zero, but not zero) and the rest of the time, slightly elevated but still OK. I tried a probability distribution function but I obviously have a problem with the distribution part.

Is it possible to calculate what the probability is of a concentration hitting 2.5 times of my highest level so far?

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you say that your data "can't be transformed". What prevents you from e.g. taking the logarithms of your data?

Comment: Using any of the standard transformations in Minitab still doesn't fit a distribution

Comment: Could you provide more details? How large is your data set? What is the uncertainty on the measurement you're taking? What is the difference between your current "close" to zero results and your desired concentration?
Also it sounds like you're working with a physical system - whether you can scale your current results to predict the probability of a certain concentration depends on the rules that dictate this, not fiddling with statistics. Do you think, given your (assumed) knowledge of the subject, that expecting 2.5 times your highest concentration is reasonable(/possible)?

Comment: Could you try to calculate the probability around the causes of this event? Do you know anything about what causes it?

Answer (score 5):

I doubt that your data truly "follows no distribution". *Anything* you would post about on CV follows a distribution.

You can estimate your probability if you fit a distribution you trust. Tail probabilities are *extremely* hard to estimate, especially as far outside your training sample as you are looking for. Your estimate will of course only be as good as your choice of distribution, so you will need to take your probability estimate with a huge grain of salt.

Maybe you want to post a follow-up question (linking to this one), where you post your data or at least a sample of it, and ask whether someone might have a good idea as to what distribution might fit, potentially after a transformation?

Comment: Thanks. Fair comment about distributions. I'll look into it again.